# How to make submenu items always open?

Tags: wordpress

I want to make submenus of vertical menu to be of the current menu item open and will not close if user click somewhere else ? I'm using UberMenu plugin for wordpress and i need it. Thanks

Comment: https://sevenspark.com/docs/ubermenu-3/settings/submenu/open-submenu-by-default try this

Comment: @HarshKhare its only for Horizontl menu align, but not for vertical.. i need to have opened sub menu item, when user clik anywhere on site...now it closes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**Force Current Submenus Open Full Time**

Appearance > UberMenu Control Panel > Main UberMenu Configuration > Submenus > Force Current Submenus Open Full Time

There is an additional setting in the Control Panel that will actually force the current submenu open full time, and not allow it to be closed.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdW36.png)

The difference is that the two settings on the individual menu items will programmatically open the submenus, but they can be closed as usual. This will force the submenu open and it cannot be closed.

Generally this is useful when trying to create a two-layer effect with your menu, using two stacked rows and then a mega menu as the third level.

```
if you intend to have your submenus open full time and don’t want it to cover open other content on your site, you’ll need to be sure to actually leave space for it in your layout
```

via [Open a submenu by default](https://sevenspark.com/docs/ubermenu-3/settings/submenu/open-submenu-by-default)

Comment: This is only for Horizontal menu not for vertical. I've said it at the top of the question.